# How to run shell script over ssh

Tags: oracle, shell, ssh, sqlplus

I have an error when run a shell script with ssh

`ssh oracle@10.33.66.109 "sh /home/oracle/Carga_hw/oracle_data.sh`

[image]

When I run it locally there are no errors.

[image]

I have to assign some permission or I have to execute the script in another way

Shell script - oracle_data.sh - Server 10.33.66.109

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
user_db="USER"
pass_db="PASS"

result=`sqlplus -s $user_db/$pass_db  <<EOF
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
set head off

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

select SYSDATE from dual;

exit;
EOF`

result=`echo $result | sed 's/ *$//g'`
echo "$result"
```

Comment: You are using `sqlplus` in your script. It seems `sqlplus` is not installed on the server that you want to run it on. Or it's not in `PATH` variable.

Comment: When I run it locally the script works fine. When I run it through ssh, it returns an error.
Sqlplus is installed.

Comment: When you run locally, do you also use `sh` (or `bash`)? The `PATH` could be different.

Comment: Locate `sqlplus` using `which sqlplus` and either add that path to `PATH` or use the full path in your script. The latter is probably best to test whether this resolves the issue or not.

Comment: if you have .oraenv configured on the other host then pass following as well to other host - "export ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID=<ORACLE_SID_ON_THAT_HOST>;. oraenv; sh ,your script name".  This will set all needed for Oracle environment. Else you can set each env variable separately - ORACLE_HOME, PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH